Dredged many global models in R (binomial GLMs), how can I compare results across models?
I'm conducting data exploration on lots of parameters (including multiple ways to summarize a parameter). I'm trying to prioritize variables for prediction onto test data. I'd like to use dredge to examine all possible combinations (and two-way interactions) to narrow down the variables to explore in more depth. What's complicated is that I have several variables in different categories: diet, sea surface temperature (SST), and NAO and only want to include one variable from each category in a model at a time. Ultimately I want to see if variance of SST is more useful than average etc, so I don't want them in the same model (and they would likely be highly correlated as well). Currently, I've created global models for each combination of variables and dredged the global model. I want to view the outputs of the top model and all models within 2 AICc, across each of the global models I assessed. At first, I'd like to just view a list of the model formula and AIC of each of those top models. Then I'd like to be able to access the summaries of the top models for further exploration.
So my questions are how to save the desired outputs and if my approach is the best way to build the models and dredge them. Thank you!
My data named Model5_Diet_EnvData_SummarizedByRegionHY_RecruitmentSummaries_SubAbbrev (first 5 rows):
structure(list(DP = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0), HI = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("MR", "MSI", "SINWR"), class = "factor"), 
    NIP = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), PP = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), MPFHMOAP = c(0.750452915231012, 
    0.453965698407607, 0.441925608384321, 0.722610207052164, 
    0.441925608384321), MHVHMOAP = c(-0.0524813927346641, 1.01282281910627, 
    0.757232590524714, 0.99109247578557, 0.757232590524714), 
    MLVHMOAP = c(0.73056230124052, 1.59501115848116, 0.598198676596868, 
    0.449493863725604, 0.598198676596868), MPFHMORAP = c(0.523489867811386, 
    0.192245391224712, 0.178793838876015, 0.492383153005024, 
    0.178793838876015), MHVHMORAP = c(-0.329148414641852, 0.788691843441836, 
    0.520497046213404, 0.765889856632941, 0.520497046213404), 
    MLVHMORAP = c(0.688793519232913, 1.70845779144675, 0.532663451086749, 
    0.357258065885503, 0.532663451086749), MPFAAP = c(0.43070772291489, 
    1.13584913195813, -0.426234961686277, -0.203429863689975, 
    -0.426234961686277), MHVAAP = c(-0.0579325416076462, 0.849585831032181, 
    0.121001819024069, -0.201997642218822, 0.121001819024069), 
    MLVAAP = c(-1.35485853425042, 0.484252451276881, 0.768258290849834, 
    1.48519986147912, 0.768258290849834), MPFVAP = c(-0.244597407127982, 
    1.27217782014326, 0.247421666481899, 0.774014226262795, 0.247421666481899
    ), MHVVAP = c(-0.37754544487536, 0.758649910763721, 0.681804652562789, 
    0.887267156622061, 0.681804652562789), MLVVAP = c(-0.572980090345317, 
    1.62888586457038, -0.0115436727418632, 0.0160827313504334, 
    -0.0115436727418632), SSTANAP = c(1.07683379079566, -1.38798265446896, 
    -0.559237858951006, 0.0697567434994638, -0.559237858951006
    ), SSTVNAP = c(2.09070187356431, 0.144862160369841, -0.853503337708263, 
    -1.68867970657618, -0.853503337708263), SSTABAAP = c(0.173411254232863, 
    -1.11203442428642, -0.473195106714148, 0.827784658554605, 
    -0.473195106714148), SSTVBAAP = c(-0.629121122035084, 0.392528189012985, 
    0.379784122762904, 0.490232696930265, 0.379784122762904), 
    NAOA = c(0.897128780719261, -0.204661067596483, -1.061094353052, 
    -0.824996528412911, -1.061094353052), NAOV = c(-0.028733326081941, 
    0.855031609762443, -0.028481970866968, 0.766860571745026, 
    -0.028481970866968)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Subset of the code I ran (my full data has ~70 global models):
# Build global models for all combinations of diet/sst/nao 
model5_diet_HI_MPFHMOAP_SSTANAP_NAOA_DRsatr_autoglm=glm(DP~(HI+MPFHMOAP+SSTANAP+NAOA)^2, data = Model5_Diet_EnvData_SummarizedByRegionHY_RecruitmentSummaries_SubAbbrev, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

model5_diet_HI_MPFHMOAP_SSTVNAP_NAOA_DRsatr_autoglm=glm(DP~(HI+MPFHMOAP+SSTVNAP+NAOA)^2, data = Model5_Diet_EnvData_SummarizedByRegionHY_RecruitmentSummaries_SubAbbrev, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

model5_diet_HI_MPFHMOAP_SSTABAAP_NAOA_DRsatr_autoglm=glm(DP~(HI+MPFHMOAP+SSTABAAP+NAOA)^2, data = Model5_Diet_EnvData_SummarizedByRegionHY_RecruitmentSummaries_SubAbbrev, family = binomial(link = "logit"))


# Dredge global models
options(na.action = "na.fail") # Required for dredge to run

model5_diet_HI_MPFHMOAP_SSTANAP_NAOA_DRdredge=dredge(model5_diet_HI_MPFHMOAP_SSTANAP_NAOA_DRsatr_autoglm, beta = "none", evaluate = TRUE, rank = AICc)

model5_diet_HI_MPFHMOAP_SSTVNAP_NAOA_DRdredge=dredge(model5_diet_HI_MPFHMOAP_SSTVNAP_NAOA_DRsatr_autoglm, beta = "none", evaluate = TRUE, rank = AICc)

model5_diet_HI_MPFHMOAP_SSTABAAP_NAOA_DRdredge=dredge(model5_diet_HI_MPFHMOAP_SSTABAAP_NAOA_DRsatr_autoglm, beta = "none", evaluate = TRUE, rank = AICc)

options(na.action = "na.omit") # set back to default

Desired output:
| Model | AIC |
| -------- | -------------- |
| DP ~ HI + NAOA + SSTANAP + HI:NAOA + HI:SSTANAP + NAOA:SSTANAP + 1    | 809.3            |
| DP ~ HI + MPFHMOAP + NAOA + HI:MPFHMOAP + HI:NAOA + 1   | 810.6            |
| DP ~ HI + MPFHMOAP + NAOA + SSTABAAP + HI:MPFHMOAP + HI:NAOA + HI:SSTABAAP + 1   | 810.8            |

Here is an approach to get your desired output consisting of models specified as character and accompanying AICc values.
Your theoretical questions (i.e., is this a good approach) are a better fit for Cross Validated.
options(na.action = "na.fail")

library(dplyr)
library(MuMIn)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

# a list containing the global models
globalmodels_topAIC <- list(
  global_model_1 = glm(mpg ~ (cyl + disp + hp + drat)^2, data = mtcars),
  global_model_2 = glm(mpg ~ (wt + qsec + vs + am)^2, data = mtcars)
) %>% 
  # for each global model dredge and make a tibble consisting of model and AICc
  map(\(global_model) {
    global_model %>% 
      dredge() %>% 
      as_tibble() %>%
      # keep only predictor columns and AICc by deselecting all others
      select(-c("(Intercept)", df, logLik, delta, weight)) %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      mutate(
        # for predictor columns replace value with name of column if not missing
        across(-AICc, ~ if_else(!is.na(.), cur_column(), NA_character_)),
        intercept = 1
      ) %>% 
      # collapse values in predictor columns by removing NAs and separate with +
      unite(model, -AICc, sep = " + ", remove = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
  }) %>% 
  # row bind resulting list of tibbles
  list_rbind() %>% 
  # sort by AICc
  arrange(AICc)%>% 
  as.data.frame()
#> Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
#> Fixed term is "(Intercept)"

globalmodels_topAIC
#>                                                                                         model
#> 1                                                                  am + qsec + wt + am:wt + 1
#> 2                                                        am + qsec + wt + am:wt + qsec:wt + 1
#> 3                                                        am + qsec + wt + am:qsec + am:wt + 1
#> 4                                                             am + qsec + vs + wt + am:wt + 1
#> 5                                              am + qsec + wt + am:qsec + am:wt + qsec:wt + 1
#> 6                                                   am + qsec + vs + wt + am:wt + qsec:wt + 1
#> 7                                                   am + qsec + vs + wt + am:wt + qsec:vs + 1
#> 8                                                                am + qsec + wt + am:qsec + 1
#> 9                                                   am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:wt + 1
#> 10                                                    am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + am:wt + 1
#> 11                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:wt + 1
#> 12                                                    am + qsec + vs + wt + am:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 13                                                                   am + vs + wt + am:wt + 1
#> 14                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + am:wt + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 15                                                                 qsec + vs + wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 16                                        am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:wt + qsec:wt + 1
#> 17                                                                         am + qsec + wt + 1
#> 18                                        am + qsec + vs + wt + am:wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + 1
#> 19                                                            am + qsec + vs + wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 20                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + am:wt + 1
#> 21                                                     am + qsec + wt + am:qsec + qsec:wt + 1
#> 22                                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + 1
#> 23                                        am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:wt + qsec:vs + 1
#> 24                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:vs + 1
#> 25                                                               am + qsec + wt + qsec:wt + 1
#> 26                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + am:wt + qsec:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 27                                                                              qsec + wt + 1
#> 28                                                           am + vs + wt + am:vs + am:wt + 1
#> 29                                            am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + am:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 30                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 31                                                           am + vs + wt + am:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 32                                  am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 33                                am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + 1
#> 34                                am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:wt + 1
#> 35                                am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:wt + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 36                                                  am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + vs:wt + 1
#> 37                                                            am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + 1
#> 38                                                       qsec + vs + wt + qsec:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 39                                                       qsec + vs + wt + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 40                                                                        vs + wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 41                                                                    am + qsec + vs + wt + 1
#> 42                                                                    qsec + wt + qsec:wt + 1
#> 43                                                                        am + wt + am:wt + 1
#> 44                                am + qsec + vs + wt + am:wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 45                                                  am + qsec + vs + wt + qsec:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 46                                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + qsec:vs + 1
#> 47                                                  am + qsec + vs + wt + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 48                                                    am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 49                              am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + 1
#> 50                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 51                                  am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + am:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 52                                                am + qsec + vs + wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + 1
#> 53                                                am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + qsec:vs + 1
#> 54                                                                         qsec + vs + wt + 1
#> 55                                am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:vs + 1
#> 56                                                             cyl + disp + hp + cyl:disp + 1
#> 57                                                  am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + 1
#> 58                                                am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + qsec:wt + 1
#> 59                                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + qsec:wt + 1
#> 60                                                                  cyl + disp + cyl:disp + 1
#> 61                                                   am + vs + wt + am:vs + am:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 62                                                               qsec + vs + wt + qsec:vs + 1
#> 63                                am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:wt + qsec:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 64                                                  am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + qsec:vs + 1
#> 65                                                                    disp + hp + disp:hp + 1
#> 66                                  am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 67                                                                   am + vs + wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 68                                                  am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + qsec:wt + 1
#> 69                                                     qsec + vs + wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + 1
#> 70                                                    cyl + disp + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:hp + 1
#> 71                                                                                vs + wt + 1
#> 72                                                               qsec + vs + wt + qsec:wt + 1
#> 73                      am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 74                                             qsec + vs + wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 75                                        am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 76                                        am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + qsec:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 77                        am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 78                        am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 79                                        am + qsec + vs + wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 80                      am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + 1
#> 81                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + qsec:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 82                                                   cyl + disp + hp + cyl:disp + disp:hp + 1
#> 83                                          am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 84                                                                           am + vs + wt + 1
#> 85                                                      cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + 1
#> 86                                am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 87                                                                   am + vs + wt + am:vs + 1
#> 88                                      am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + 1
#> 89                                                           cyl + disp + drat + cyl:disp + 1
#> 90                                                               cyl + disp + hp + cyl:hp + 1
#> 91                                        am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + 1
#> 92                                am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + qsec:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 93                                        am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + qsec:vs + 1
#> 94                        am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 95                                                              cyl + disp + hp + disp:hp + 1
#> 96                                        am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + qsec:wt + 1
#> 97                                                             disp + drat + hp + disp:hp + 1
#> 98                                                           am + vs + wt + am:vs + vs:wt + 1
#> 99                                          cyl + disp + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:hp + disp:hp + 1
#> 100                                            cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:hp + 1
#> 101                                                                                    wt + 1
#> 102                             am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 103                                                    cyl + disp + hp + cyl:hp + disp:hp + 1
#> 104                               am + qsec + vs + wt + am:vs + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 105                                              cyl + disp + drat + cyl:disp + disp:drat + 1
#> 106                                          cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + 1
#> 107                                           cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + drat:hp + 1
#> 108                                               cyl + disp + drat + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + 1
#> 109                                           cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + disp:hp + 1
#> 110                                         cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + disp:drat + 1
#> 111                                                       cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:hp + 1
#> 112             am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + am:wt + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 113                                                disp + drat + hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + 1
#> 114                                                      cyl + disp + drat + hp + disp:hp + 1
#> 115                                                               disp + drat + disp:drat + 1
#> 116                                                  disp + drat + hp + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 117                                                                     cyl + hp + cyl:hp + 1
#> 118                             am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + 1
#> 119                                                                            cyl + disp + 1
#> 120                     am + qsec + vs + wt + am:qsec + am:vs + qsec:vs + qsec:wt + vs:wt + 1
#> 121                                                                      disp + drat + hp + 1
#> 122                                 cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + 1
#> 123                                  cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 124                                                                               am + wt + 1
#> 125                                                              cyl + drat + hp + cyl:hp + 1
#> 126                                  cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:hp + disp:hp + 1
#> 127                                cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:hp + disp:drat + 1
#> 128                                                         cyl + disp + drat + disp:drat + 1
#> 129                                                          cyl + disp + drat + cyl:drat + 1
#> 130                                                          disp + drat + hp + disp:drat + 1
#> 131                                                                             disp + hp + 1
#> 132                                                                       cyl + drat + hp + 1
#> 133                                                                                   cyl + 1
#> 134                                                                       cyl + disp + hp + 1
#> 135                                           cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:hp + disp:drat + 1
#> 136                                                                     cyl + disp + drat + 1
#> 137                                             cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:hp + disp:hp + 1
#> 138                                                            disp + drat + hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 139                                   cyl + disp + drat + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + disp:drat + 1
#> 140                                            cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + 1
#> 141                                                                             drat + hp + 1
#> 142                                 cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 143                                                                              cyl + hp + 1
#> 144                                                                                  disp + 1
#> 145                                                                            cyl + drat + 1
#> 146                                cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + disp:hp + 1
#> 147                               cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + disp:drat + disp:hp + 1
#> 148                                             cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 149                                                                cyl + disp + drat + hp + 1
#> 150                                                                 cyl + drat + cyl:drat + 1
#> 151                                cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 152                              cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + disp:drat + 1
#> 153                                           cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + disp:hp + 1
#> 154                               cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + disp:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 155                                      disp + drat + hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 156                                          cyl + disp + drat + hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + 1
#> 157                                            cyl + disp + drat + hp + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 158                                                            cyl + drat + hp + cyl:drat + 1
#> 159                                                                           disp + drat + 1
#> 160                                                     cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + 1
#> 161                                                             cyl + drat + hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 162                                                    cyl + disp + drat + hp + disp:drat + 1
#> 163                                                   cyl + drat + hp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + 1
#> 164                                                    cyl + drat + hp + cyl:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 165                                              cyl + disp + drat + cyl:drat + disp:drat + 1
#> 166                                                      cyl + disp + drat + hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 167                                                disp + drat + hp + disp:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 168                       cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:hp + 1
#> 169                                 cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:hp + disp:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 170                      cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:hp + disp:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 171                                                                   drat + hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 172                        cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:hp + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 173                     cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:drat + 1
#> 174                       cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 175                      cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + 1
#> 176                                 cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 177                                 cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + 1
#> 178                                  cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:hp + 1
#> 179                                cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:drat + 1
#> 180                                   cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:hp + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 181                                  cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 182                                cyl + disp + drat + hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 183                               cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + disp:drat + disp:hp + 1
#> 184                     cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + disp:drat + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 185                      cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 186                                                  cyl + drat + hp + cyl:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 187                    cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + disp:drat + disp:hp + 1
#> 188                                                              am + qsec + vs + am:qsec + 1
#> 189                    cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + disp:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 190                                         cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + disp:drat + 1
#> 191                                           cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 192                                          cyl + disp + drat + hp + disp:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 193                                                                   am + qsec + am:qsec + 1
#> 194                                         cyl + drat + hp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 195                                                                        am + qsec + vs + 1
#> 196           cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + 1
#> 197                                                                             am + qsec + 1
#> 198                                                                               am + vs + 1
#> 199                       cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 200                      cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 201             cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 202                                                                am + qsec + vs + am:vs + 1
#> 203           cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 204            cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 205                        cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 206                     cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + disp:drat + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 207                                                      am + qsec + vs + am:qsec + am:vs + 1
#> 208                                                                       am + vs + am:vs + 1
#> 209                      cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + 1
#> 210                                                              am + qsec + vs + qsec:vs + 1
#> 211                                                    am + qsec + vs + am:qsec + qsec:vs + 1
#> 212                               cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + disp:drat + drat:hp + 1
#> 213          cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + disp:drat + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 214                                                      am + qsec + vs + am:vs + qsec:vs + 1
#> 215 cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:disp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 216            cyl + disp + drat + hp + cyl:drat + cyl:hp + disp:drat + disp:hp + drat:hp + 1
#> 217                                            am + qsec + vs + am:qsec + am:vs + qsec:vs + 1
#> 218                                                                                    hp + 1
#> 219                                                                                  drat + 1
#> 220                                                                                    vs + 1
#> 221                                                                             qsec + vs + 1
#> 222                                                                                    am + 1
#> 223                                                                   qsec + vs + qsec:vs + 1
#> 224                                                                                  qsec + 1
#> 225                                                                                         1
#> 226                                                                                         1
#>         AICc
#> 1   147.7336
#> 2   149.0083
#> 3   150.8206
#> 4   151.0402
#> 5   152.2860
#> 6   152.5927
#> 7   154.1952
#> 8   154.3050
#> 9   154.4147
#> 10  154.5234
#> 11  154.5632
#> 12  154.6156
#> 13  155.3045
#> 14  155.5000
#> 15  155.9726
#> 16  156.1921
#> 17  156.4271
#> 18  156.4529
#> 19  156.7605
#> 20  157.3624
#> 21  157.6063
#> 22  157.6106
#> 23  157.6837
#> 24  158.0734
#> 25  158.0844
#> 26  158.1030
#> 27  158.2020
#> 28  158.2414
#> 29  158.2583
#> 30  158.3340
#> 31  158.5707
#> 32  158.6087
#> 33  158.6446
#> 34  158.7698
#> 35  158.8777
#> 36  158.9134
#> 37  159.0775
#> 38  159.1334
#> 39  159.2779
#> 40  159.4457
#> 41  159.4793
#> 42  159.5843
#> 43  159.7837
#> 44  159.7933
#> 45  159.8672
#> 46  160.0380
#> 47  160.3219
#> 48  160.3545
#> 49  160.4727
#> 50  160.5169
#> 51  160.6676
#> 52  160.7307
#> 53  160.8759
#> 54  161.0159
#> 55  161.0339
#> 56  161.0998
#> 57  161.1938
#> 58  161.1991
#> 59  161.3821
#> 60  161.4571
#> 61  161.7869
#> 62  161.9377
#> 63  161.9770
#> 64  162.0851
#> 65  162.2164
#> 66  162.2678
#> 67  162.3081
#> 68  162.4574
#> 69  162.5145
#> 70  162.5532
#> 71  162.5761
#> 72  162.6361
#> 73  162.6531
#> 74  162.6545
#> 75  162.7628
#> 76  162.7683
#> 77  163.1019
#> 78  163.3192
#> 79  163.3466
#> 80  163.3592
#> 81  163.7302
#> 82  163.9840
#> 83  164.2428
#> 84  164.2719
#> 85  164.2808
#> 86  164.2855
#> 87  164.2942
#> 88  164.3435
#> 89  164.3818
#> 90  164.6133
#> 91  164.6221
#> 92  164.6745
#> 93  164.7967
#> 94  164.9646
#> 95  165.0930
#> 96  165.1087
#> 97  165.2344
#> 98  165.6142
#> 99  165.9542
#> 100 166.1438
#> 101 166.8866
#> 102 167.0515
#> 103 167.1616
#> 104 167.3447
#> 105 167.3986
#> 106 167.4436
#> 107 167.5470
#> 108 167.5763
#> 109 167.5770
#> 110 167.5883
#> 111 167.7054
#> 112 167.8586
#> 113 168.3047
#> 114 168.3545
#> 115 168.5005
#> 116 168.5043
#> 117 168.5943
#> 118 168.6188
#> 119 168.6271
#> 120 168.8845
#> 121 169.3284
#> 122 169.4279
#> 123 169.4288
#> 124 169.5107
#> 125 169.5468
#> 126 169.7700
#> 127 169.8009
#> 128 169.8376
#> 129 169.9034
#> 130 169.9637
#> 131 170.1000
#> 132 170.1171
#> 133 170.1636
#> 134 170.3261
#> 135 170.6409
#> 136 170.7090
#> 137 170.7554
#> 138 170.8182
#> 139 170.9187
#> 140 170.9372
#> 141 170.9861
#> 142 171.0134
#> 143 171.0433
#> 144 171.0665
#> 145 171.1001
#> 146 171.1473
#> 147 171.1649
#> 148 171.1978
#> 149 171.2960
#> 150 171.3503
#> 151 171.3601
#> 152 171.3644
#> 153 171.4444
#> 154 171.4650
#> 155 171.5689
#> 156 171.7663
#> 157 171.9437
#> 158 172.0425
#> 159 172.2185
#> 160 172.3616
#> 161 172.4311
#> 162 172.4918
#> 163 172.7735
#> 164 172.8513
#> 165 172.9799
#> 166 173.0097
#> 167 173.0658
#> 168 173.0757
#> 169 173.2757
#> 170 173.4749
#> 171 173.4991
#> 172 173.5216
#> 173 173.6485
#> 174 173.6562
#> 175 173.8606
#> 176 174.2266
#> 177 174.3431
#> 178 174.3893
#> 179 174.5019
#> 180 174.6701
#> 181 174.7195
#> 182 175.1133
#> 183 175.2016
#> 184 175.2960
#> 185 175.3076
#> 186 175.3230
#> 187 175.4209
#> 188 175.5767
#> 189 175.6484
#> 190 175.8848
#> 191 175.9479
#> 192 176.0391
#> 193 176.0943
#> 194 176.2263
#> 195 176.3883
#> 196 176.5857
#> 197 177.0837
#> 198 177.1610
#> 199 177.3924
#> 200 177.5698
#> 201 177.6959
#> 202 177.8747
#> 203 177.9548
#> 204 177.9863
#> 205 178.0329
#> 206 178.4071
#> 207 178.4757
#> 208 178.5041
#> 209 178.6373
#> 210 178.6508
#> 211 178.8583
#> 212 179.6764
#> 213 180.0194
#> 214 181.1160
#> 215 181.7312
#> 216 182.0494
#> 217 182.0697
#> 218 182.0958
#> 219 191.6571
#> 220 193.0043
#> 221 194.8837
#> 222 197.3415
#> 223 197.6783
#> 224 205.4453
#> 225 209.1693
#> 226 209.1693

Created on 2024-09-05 with reprex v2.1.1

Great! I edited the code a bit to save the output as a dataframe.
